# Funcão Javascript não funciona

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma função que funciona no meu teste feito no bloco de notas, mas no projeto não funciona.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function MostrarEsconderDiv(div) {

            if (document.getElementById(div).style.display == "none") { <---AQUI DA ERRO --->
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById(div).value = "aberta";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById(div).value = "";
            }
        }
    </script>

</head>

<body>
<table>
                               <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" height="10">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" valign="top">
                            <div class="Section">
                                <div class="SectionHeader">
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <img align="absMiddle" hspace="4" src="/images/internas/seta3.gif" />
                                                <a id="A3" class="linkFormularios" href="javascript:MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui</a>
                                                <br />
                                                (abrirá um formulário nesta mesma página para você preencher)
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div id="spacer" style="margin-top: 5px">
                                </div>
                                <div id="divSecao6" style="display:none;  margin-left: 30px" runat="server">
                                    <table id="idSecao6Table" width="100%">
                                        <!-- SECAO 6 -->
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="15">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#ececec" height="21">
                                                <b>6 - Apenas para Sistema Integrado de Gestão</b>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#f5f5f5">
                                                Responda a esta seção apenas se você estiver interessado em uma certificação integrada (opcional).
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <font color="#666666"><b>A Política e o Manual do Sistema de Gestão são integrados?</b></font>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblPoliticaManualSistemaIntegrados" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sim" Text="Sim"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Não" Text="Não"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <font color="#666666"><b>Os procedimentos de gestão (ex: Controle Documentos, Auditorias) são integrados?</b></font>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblProcGestaoIntegrados" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sim" Text="Sim, pelo menos 80% dos procedimentos de gestão são integrados"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Não" Text="Não"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td bgcolor="#cccccc" height="1">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td height="5">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <font color="#666666"><b>Os procedimentos operacionais (ex: Controle de produção) são integrados?</b></font>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblProcOperacionaisIntegrados" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Sim" Text="Sim, pelo menos 80% dos procedimentos operacionais são integrados"></asp:ListItem>
                                                    <asp:ListItem Value="Não" Text="Não"></asp:ListItem>
                                                </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <!-- FIM - ESCONDE SEÇÃO 6  -->
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você já viu no console qual é a mensagem de erro que dá?

Comment: @JoelRodrigues da "Object Required"

Comment: Funciona bem para mim... ---> http://jsfiddle.net/6nj8djdo/ Podes explicar o que fica errado nesse exemplo?

Comment: @Sergio Então, fora da aplicação funciona, mas dentro não funciona.

Comment: @AndreeH tens essa aplicação online para podermos ver? senão fica dificil reproduzir o problema e poder ajudar.

Comment: @Sergio, cara depois de um tempo tentando muitas coisas, fui perceber que era asp.net pelo runat="server" e então coloquei o  ClientIDMode="Static" e funcionou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percebi que você está usando ASP.NET Web Forms, certo? O ID de alguns elementos é alterado em tempo de execução, isso pode estar causando o problema. Coloque, por exemplo, um `alert(div)` dentro da função para ver se o ID está sendo passado como esperado e inspecione o elemento no browser para ver se ele está com o mesmo ID.

Comment: Puts @Joel Rodrigues, to ligado nisso, mexo com asp.net, mas nesse caso to mexendo com asp clássico que não manjo muito, e sei um pouco de javascript também mas esse erro me tirou do sério rs.

Answer (score 1):

Assim como disse na outra resposta, o seu erro acontece, porque no seu elemento não existe nenhum atributo display definido.

```
getElementById(div).style.display == "none"
```

O que essa linha de código significa:

"Compare o atributo display do elemento com tal ID e compare com none"

Como o atributo display não existe na definição de seu elemento, o erro é gerado.

**Correção**

Edite o elemento HTML chamado pela função e adicione `style="display:none"`

Por exemplo:

Se o seu elemento era:

```
<div id="seuDiv"></div>
```

ele deve ficar:

```
<div id="seuDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: Consegui. Adicionei um ClientIDMode="Static" na div que eu queria pegar o id e foi. Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 0):

Tente trocar:

```
<a id="A3" class="linkFormularios" href="javascript:MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui</a>
```

Por

```
<span id="A3" class="linkFormularios" onclick="MostrarEsconderDiv('divSecao6')">Para Sistema Integrado de Gestão, clique aqui</span>
```

Algumas aplicações costumam dar bug quando usamos a tag de link...

Editado: A div está rorando no servidor e a o script rodando do lado do cliente, acompanhar comentários

Comment: Não adianta @jefissu .. :S

Comment: Acho que é por que seu div está carregado no servidor e vc está tentando escondê-lo pelo cliente então. tente colocar um runat="server" na div que executa a função. tente deixar também a função js no lado do server

Comment: então, eu creio que pode ser isso. Como mudo isso, sabe ?

Comment: Experimente excluir este runar server desta div div e mode-o para a tabela, acho q deve resolver

Comment: No Asp classico vc não precisa definir nenhum controle com runat server, pelo menos eu não uso nada rodando no servidor relacionado a controles...

Comment: Então @jefissu, tá tudo misturado essa zica aqui. Eu percebi isso também agora e fiz o teste, joguei um ClientIDMode="Static" e consegui.

Comment: Ok, só não esqueça de marcar a questão como resolvida então

Comment: @AndreeH Isso é do ASP.Net, sinal que você não está usando asp clássico...

Comment: @bfavaretto é cara, eu percebi quando eu vi o runat="server", ai coloquei o  ClientIDMode="Static" e funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui colocando ClientIDMode="Static" no elemento em que eu precisava pegar o ID e passar como parâmetro para a function.